# Open Alarm feature of Android?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, alarm

I have read many questions regarding how to set `Alarm` through your application. But here I want to open the `Alarm` built-in function or option of `Android` through my application. I don't think that `Alarm` is an application of Android; if it's not so, how can we get access to this feature of Android?

Comment: https://resocoder.com/2018/01/05/make-a-timer-app-countdown-timer-ep-2-android-kotlin-tutorial-code/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android OS is providing Alarm Manager component, and all manufacturer provide own way for set Alarm in the device, so all device has different inbuilt Alarm application with different package name, so you can't able to use that package name hardcoded in your own app for open inbuilt app for all the devices.

Here You have to develop your own application with alarm manager component with your own way, Not any options for access device inbuilt setting.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why but Android does not give access to the some of built in features like **Alarm**
**Developer option** etc

check out this one https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms